# TV series or movie about a boy who died in a shipwreck and the girl he appears to

Tags: story-identification, tv

15+ years ago I was watching tv and I saw probably a tv series episode.

It was about a little boy that died in a shipwreck years ago. He appeared in front of a girl in a school.  The girl chased the boy, he took a turn and the girl followed there was a wet well and the boy disappeared.

The girl somehow was searching about that boy and she found on her laptop a picture of a ship that was starting its journey. She saw the little boy with his family in the picture and when she zoomed in the photo, the boy inside the photo turned his head and looked at her and then water came out of her laptop.

Comment: Is "wet well" supposed to be "wet swell?" "wet smell?

Comment: Is the genre of this horror? Comedy? Romance? Drama?

What country/language did you see this in? Was it animated or live action?

How old were both characters and do you remember what they looked like?

Comment: The question does describe the boy as a "little boy" .  To me a "little boy" should be about 3 feet tall, a "birg boy" should be fully grown teenager, and a "medium sized boy" should be about 12 years old.  But that leaves a lot of uncertainty about the transitions between the categories.  And I have noticed that many people use those categories very loosely and imprcisely.